# почему return возвращает None в рекурсивной функции

Tags: python, рекурсия

```
def input_cmd():
    pc_amount = input('Please input Amount of PCs :   ')
    if pc_amount > 0:
        return pc_amount
    else:
        print('Please enter a value greater than Zero')
        input_cmd()

print(input_cmd())
```

Comment: те если вводить больше zero то она срабатывает и выводит, а если меньше или ноль она тоже срабатывает, но возвращает None:

Comment: Можно например `return` добавить перед `input_cmd()`. Но все равно рекурсия тут как то не смотрится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что в случае, если pc_amount > 0, функция ничего не возвращает, return нет:

```
def input_cmd():
    pc_amount = input('Please input Amount of PCs :   ')
    if int(pc_amount) > 0:
        return pc_amount
    else:
        print('Please enter a value greater than Zero')
        return input_cmd()
```

Comment: Спасибо, так получилось.

Comment: Если ввести -5, выполнится ветка else, функция будет вызывана ещё раз и запросит pc_amount, получит 5, в ней выполнится ветка if, произойдёт возврат значения 5 в ветку else первого вызова функции, в которой инструкции return нет, а потому ничего не будет возвращено.

Comment: Для спасибо есть кнопка "Принять".